# Firebase Cloud Functions Array Parameter Undefined

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to put an array as a parameter for cloud functions. In my code, the array shows up correct, but in the logs for the cloud function it shows up as undefined.

Array Result:
["user1", "user2"]

Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.chatNotifications = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const title = data.title;
  const payloadMsg = data.message;
  const memberList = data.membersList;

  functions.logger.log("Member List:", memberList);
  for (let i = 0; i < memberList.count; i++) {
    const memberName = memberList[i];
    const message = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: payloadMsg,
      },
      topic: memberName,
      apns: {
        payload: {
          aps: {
            badge: "1",
          },
        },
      },
    };

    admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
          // Response is a message ID string.
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
  }
});
```

Code:

```
functions.httpsCallable("chatNotifications").call(["title": chatName, "message": name + " has been added to the group", "memberList": memberList]) { (result, error) in
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                            let message = error.localizedDescription
                            print(message)
                        }
                    }
                    if let text = result?.data as? String {
                        print("Result: ", text)
                        
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that in your code you are sending this:

```
"memberList": memberList
```

But in the cloud function you have this:

```
data.membersList
```

The name of the data is different, also use

```
memberList.length
```

instead of

```
memberList.count
```